# What widget is normally used to create this side bar. [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Do anyone know what is the official name of this side bar. Is it count as navigation bar?
If I would like to make a design like this in flutter, what widget should I used?
Not sure if the pageviewbuilder can help me to do it.

Please click on this
[image]
to check out the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for a NavigationRail

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html

Comment: Yes! I am sure it is what I want! Thank you sir!

Comment: Consider a NavigationRail is fine on big screens (tablets, etc.). On small screens you should use other types of navigation widgets

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on this? coz I will make it based on small screen. (Normal phone)

Comment: On normal devices you use normaly a TabBar or a BottomNavigationBar or a Drawer, NavigationRail will take too much space

Comment: @MrDoufy If you find this answer is helpful, consider accepting it.